# Python & Multiprocessing, breaking a set generation down into sub-processes

Tags: python, list, set, multiprocessing, locks

I've got to generate a set of strings based on some calculations of other strings.  This takes quite a while, and I'm working on a multiprocessor/multicore server so I figured that I could break these tasks down into chunks and pass them off to different process.

Firstly I break the first list of strings down into chunks of 10000 each, send this off to a process which creates a new set, then try to obtain a lock and report these back to the master process.  However, my master processes's set is empty!

Here's some code:

```
def build_feature_labels(self,strings,return_obj,l):
    feature_labels = set()
    for s in strings:
        feature_labels = feature_labels.union(s.get_feature_labels())
    print "method: ", len(feature_labels)
    l.acquire()
    return_obj.return_feature_labels(feature_labels)
    l.release()
    print "Thread Done"

def return_feature_labels(self,labs):
    self.feature_labels = self.feature_labels.union(labs)
    print "length self", len(self.feature_labels)
    print "length labs", len(labs)


current_pos = 0
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

while current_pos < len(orig_strings):
    while len(multiprocessing.active_children()) > threads:
        print "WHILE: cpu count", str(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
            T.sleep(30)

    print "number of processes", str(len(multiprocessing.active_children()))
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.build_feature_labels,args=(orig_strings[current_pos:current_pos+self.MAX_ITEMS],self,lock))
    proc.start()
    current_pos = current_pos + self.MAX_ITEMS

    while len(multiprocessing.active_children()) > 0:
        T.sleep(3)


    print len(self.feature_labels)
```

What is strange is a) that self.feature_labels on the master process is empty, but when it is called from each sub-process it has items.  I think I'm taking the wrong approach here (it's how I used to do it in Java!).  Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a pool of workers: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers. This does a lot of the work for you in a map-reduce style and returns the assembled results.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [multiprocessing.Pipe, or Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) (or other such object) to pass data between processes. Use a Pipe to pass data between two processes, and a Queue to allow multiple producers and consumers.

Along with the official documentation, there are nice examples to be found in [Doug Hellman's multiprocessing tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/index.html). In particular, it has an example of how to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to implement a mapreduce-type operation. It might suit your purposes very well.

Comment: with a multiprocessing Queue, does this mean that I keep track of all my currently Queues (in a Python list?), within each sub-processes do something like queue.put(the_set_I_created), and then in the master process go through the list of Queues and call q.get to get the set?

Comment: @Stuart: You could do that, though come to think of it, there is a nice example using a `multiprocessing.Pool` in Doug Hellman's tutorial which I think might be simpler. See the mapreduce example: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html

Answer (score 0):

Why it didn't work: multiprocessing uses processes, and process memory isn't shared. Multiprocessing can set up shared memory or pipes for IPC, but it must be done explicitly. This is how the various suggestions send data back to the master.